# (Считывание/Запись) работа с файлами С++

Tags: c++, файлы, vector, fstream, ifstream

У меня есть файл с 40 вопросами. Моя задача, поместить все 40 вопросов в вектрок, после чего, выводить от туда один рандомный вопрос. Не могу справиться с задачей. Ошибка в плане логики.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int randString = 0;

    vector <string> q;
    string s;

    std::ifstream in("questions.txt");
    if (in.is_open())
        while (cin >> s) q.push_back(s);
    else cout << "ERROR";

    in.close();

    randString = rand() % 40 + 1;
    cout << q[randString] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В файле вопросы хранятся так:

1. Что такое класс? Чем отличается класс от объекта?
2. Допускается ли передавать объекты в качестве параметров, и какими способами? А возвращать как результат?
3. Чем класс отличается от структуры? Можно ли использовать ключевые слова public и private в структуре?

и т.д

Comment: Т.е. вопрос может занимать несколько строк? Между строками есть разделитель в виде пустой строки? Ну, а самая первая ошибка - вы, как и многие другие, почему-то не читаете документацию и уверены, что `cin >> s` читает **строку**, в то время как этот оператор читает **слово**...

Comment: Все вопросы в одну строку, здесь сайт, перенес. Разделителя в виде пустой строки нету. Понял ошибку, как это все можно исправить ? Не подскажите в виде кода ?) Заранее, спасибо

Comment: @titov вместо `cin` использовать `getline()`

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev,  использовать cin.getline() или просто getline() и что вообще нужно передавать как параметры ? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(getline(in, s))
   q.push_back(s);
```

Comment: ну и где же разделитель  "?" ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так ТС же написал, что каждый вопрос - новая строка.А на примере видно, что в одном вопросе может содержаться несколько вопросов: `2. Допускается ли передавать объекты в качестве параметров, и какими способами? А возвращать как результат?`